# How to access a group of files, regardless of folder name with fs/require

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

So I have a group of files organized like this:

```
./main/folder1/files.js
./main/differentfolder/files.js
./main/test/files.js
./main/test/files.js
```

The files are NOT named files.js, it's my way of saying that there's a lot of files in that folder.

How do I access all the files shown above without doing something like this:

```js
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./main/folder1/files.js`)
const commandFiles2 = fs.readdirSync(`./main/differentfolder/files.js`)
const commandFiles3 = fs.readdirSync(`./main/test/files.js`)
//and so on
```

Just grab all the Javascript files inside "main" regardless of the folder name, both using "[fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)" and "[require](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)". I'd expect it to be the same. There is nothing but folders in ./main.

EDIT: I just want it so fs can check /main//files instead of what's inside of main

Comment: you need to iterate through the folders. (there is no glob in nodejs fs iirc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I easily solved this problem by using the require-all package which was something installed with the other packages I'm using for my app:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
var folders = fs.readdirSync('./main/').filter(n => n !== '.DS_Store') //filter out that disgusting macOS file

folders.forEach(async (folder) => {
  var cmdfolder = Object.values(require('require-all')(__dirname + `/main/${folder}`))
  cmdfolder.forEach(async (key) => {
  var file = require(`./main/${folder}/${key.fileName}`)'
  //register file
  })
})
```